# a hadith about which leg should we put on our shoes first?

Tags: hadith

I know which leg I should put first but I wanted the hadith and its meaning, that's why I asked this question .plus please answer my question . it is urgent .

Answer (score 1):

This single incident was collected in several books of hadith, all reported through Abu Huraira, Rasulullah said:

**إِذَا انْتَعَلَ أَحَدُكُمْ فَلْيَبْدَأْ بِالْيُمْنَى وَإِذَا خَلَعَ فَلْيَبْدَأْ بِالشِّمَالِ وَلْيُنْعِلْهُمَا جَمِيعًا أَوْ لِيَخْلَعْهُمَا جَمِيعًا**

**When one of you puts on sandals, he should first put in the right foot, and when he takes off he should take off the left one first, or he should put them on together or take them off together.**

[Muwatta, Musnad Ahmed, Sahihayn, Jami at-Tirmidhi, Sunan Abu Dawud]